# Compiled Runtime Ordering of Watchers in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

So, let's hypothetically say I have the following setup:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
const someRef = ref<null | string>(null)

const setSomeRef = (v: string) => {
    someRef.value = v
}

const watcher1 = watch(someRef, () => {
    doSomething()
})

const watcher2 = watch(someRef, () => {
    doSomethingElse()
})
</script>
```

```html
<template>
    <button @click="setSomeRef("Hello!")">Hit Me!</button>
</template>
```

Let's also just hypothetically imagine that these two watchers might be in two different composables, but maybe instantiated on the same component ... for reasons.

A user clicks the button.

My thought is, which function fires first? `doSomething()` or `doSomethingElse()?

Do they always fire in the same order? ... and does it matter if the side effects are unrelated, i.e., is the perceived difference negligible?

Comment: It's safe to assume that watchers are executed in the same order they are set. And no, it doesn't matter if you don't rely on the order implicitly (you shouldn't)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this should not be a concern in JavaScript. And you are proberbly doing something wrong, if you need this. You need more control and predictability than this.

I did a very small test, that might help you.
Seems like the code runs synchronous (as expected in JavaScript) with less than .3 milliseconds in between (on my machine).

[Test in Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cCBsYW5nPVwidHNcIj5cbmltcG9ydCB7cmVmLCB3YXRjaH0gZnJvbSAndnVlJ1xuY29uc3QgdGVzdCA9IHJlZihbXSlcbmNvbnN0IHNvbWVSZWYgPSByZWYoMClcbmNvbnN0IHNldFNvbWVSZWYgPSAoKSA9PiB7XG4gICAgc29tZVJlZi52YWx1ZSsrXG59XG5jb25zdCB3YXRjaGVyMSA9IHdhdGNoKHNvbWVSZWYsICgpID0+IHtcbiAgdGVzdC52YWx1ZS5wdXNoKFwiMTogXCIgKyB3aW5kb3cucGVyZm9ybWFuY2Uubm93KCkpXG4gICAgY29uc29sZS5sb2coXCIxOiBcIiwgd2luZG93LnBlcmZvcm1hbmNlLm5vdygpKVxufSlcbmNvbnN0IHdhdGNoZXIyID0gd2F0Y2goc29tZVJlZiwgKCkgPT4ge1xuICAgIHRlc3QudmFsdWUucHVzaChcIjI6IFwiICsgd2luZG93LnBlcmZvcm1hbmNlLm5vdygpKVxuICAgIGNvbnNvbGUubG9nKFwiMjogXCIsIHdpbmRvdy5wZXJmb3JtYW5jZS5ub3coKSlcbn0pXG48L3NjcmlwdD5cblxuPHRlbXBsYXRlPlxuICA8YnV0dG9uIEBjbGljaz1cInNldFNvbWVSZWYoKVwiPkhpdCBNZSE8L2J1dHRvbj5cbiAgPGRpdiB2LWZvcj1cImkgaW4gdGVzdFwiPlxuICAgIHt7aX19XG4gIDwvZGl2PlxuPC90ZW1wbGF0ZT4iLCJpbXBvcnQtbWFwLmpzb24iOiJ7XG4gIFwiaW1wb3J0c1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJ2dWVcIjogXCJodHRwczovL3NmYy52dWVqcy5vcmcvdnVlLnJ1bnRpbWUuZXNtLWJyb3dzZXIuanNcIlxuICB9XG59In0=)

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import {ref, watch} from 'vue'
const test = ref([])
const someRef = ref(0)
const setSomeRef = () => {
    someRef.value++
}
const watcher1 = watch(someRef, () => {
  test.value.push("1: " + window.performance.now())
    console.log("1: ", window.performance.now())
})
const watcher2 = watch(someRef, () => {
    test.value.push("2: " + window.performance.now())
    console.log("2: ", window.performance.now())
})
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="setSomeRef()">Hit Me!</button>
  <div v-for="i in test">
    {{i}}
  </div>
</template>
```